# How to do "OR" filter in slick

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, slick, slick-2.0

In slick we can use

```
query.filter( m => (m.state === state1 && m.status === status1) || (m.state === state2 && m.status == status2))
```

for an "OR" condition in where clause. However my requirement is I have "OR" conditions in a list (passed by user as part of URL). Conditions list includes tuples of state and status like

```
List[(state1, status1),(state2, status2),(state3, status3)]
```

So what I wanted was to either be able to build the || statement inside of filter so that I can use each of the conditions from the list to generate the query but I am not sure how to achieve that. Or if there is something like

```
query.applyOrFilters.orFilter(condition1).orFilter(condition2)
```

which will actually do condition1 OR condition2 on query object.
Is it possible with Slick or with for comprehensions as of now ?

Comment: If you need something more composable, based on predicate, conjunctions and disjunctions (a bit like Hibernate/JPA Criteria API), you can check my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28281232/slick-create-query-conjunctions-disjunctions-dynamically/28303670#28303670

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While playing around with it, I finally found a way to do it:-

```
query.filter {
  m => conditions.map(n => m._13 === n._1 && m._14 === n._2).reduceLeft(_ || _)
}
```

where `conditions` is of the form `List[(String,String)]`, `m._13` maps to state and `m._14` maps to status.

Hopefully this will help someone trying out same thing.