# How to filter with a list of ADTs in scala with slick 3.2

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I have a list of the following case class

```
case class caseClass
(
  field1: Option[String],
  field2: Option[String],
  field3: Option[String]
)
```

These fields are corresponding to the columns of a mySQL table, which I want to search in. Basically I want to filter with each of the case class instances, where there is an AND relation between field1,field2 and field3 and an OR relation between the instances. In SQL it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    field4,
    field5
FROM
    tablename
WHERE
    (field1 = ? AND field2 = ?) OR
    (field3 = ?) OR 
    (field1 = ? AND field2 = ? AND field3 = ?) OR 
    ...etc
```

Of course it would be generated with string concatenations as all the case class fields are all optional. 
How can I solve this with slick elegantly (not using slick's plain SQL queries)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out how to solve this problem based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28194746)

```
def queryGenerator
(
  listOfCaseClasses: List[CaseClass],
  table: TableQuery[CaseClassvTable]
) = {
  val query = table.filter { row =>
    listOfCaseClasses.map { parameter =>
      List(
        (row.field1vTable === parameter.field1, parameter.field1),
        (row.field2vTable === parameter.field2, parameter.field2),
        (row.field3vTable === parameter.field3, parameter.field3),
      ).collect{ case (x, Some(_)) => x }.reduce(_ && _)
    }.reduce(_ || _)
  }.result
  query
}
```

I couldn't figure out how to filter based on the Rep[Option[Boolean]] expressions (which are the first part of the tuple), so I thought I make the list a list of tuples where the second part is the parameters of the CaseClass. And it's easy to filter plain Option[_]'s.