# Slick: create query conjunctions/disjunctions dynamically

Tags: scala, slick, play-slick

I'm trying to create a typesafe dynamic DSL for a Slick table but not sure how to achieve this.

Users can post filters to the server by sending filters in form/json format, and I need to build a Slick query with all that.

So basically this means transforming a Scala case class representing my filters to a Slick query.

It seems the "predicates" can have 3 different shapes. I've seen the trait `CanBeQueryCondition`. Can I fold over these different possible shapes?

I've seen the extension methods `&&` and `||` and know there is something to do with this but I just don't know how to do.

Basically, I have a list of predicates which takes the following types:

```
(PatientTable) => Column[Option[Boolean]]
```

or

```
(PatientTable) => Column[Boolean]
```

The problem to me is that there is not a single supertype for all the 3 different types that have a `CanBeQueryCondition`, so I don't really know how do fold the predicates with `&&` as once added to the list these differently shaped predicate takes a very generic type `List[(PatientTable) => Column[_ >: Boolean with Option[Boolean]]]`.

Also, I'm not sure about what can be considered a predicate in Slick. A composable predicate seems to be `Column[Boolean]`, but actually the `filter` method only accept parameters of type `(PatientTable) => Column[Boolean]`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'm answering my own question with what I've finally built.

**Let's define a simple case class and row mapper**

```
case class User(
                    id: String = java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString,
                    companyScopeId: String,
                    firstName: Option[String] = None,
                    lastName: Option[String] = None
                    ) 


class UserTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[User](tag,"USER") {
  override def id = column[String]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
  def companyScopeId = column[String]("company_scope_id", O.NotNull)
  def firstName = column[Option[String]]("first_name", O.Nullable)
  def lastName = column[Option[String]]("last_name", O.Nullable)

  def * = (id, companyScopeId, firstName, lastName) <>
    (User.tupled,User.unapply)
}
```

**Notion of predicate in Slick**

I assume that the notion of "predicate" is what can be put inside `TableQuery.filter`. But this type is rather complex as it is a function that takes a `Table` and returns a type that has an implicit `CanBeQueryCondition`

Unfornunately for me there are 3 different types that have a `CanBeQueryCondition` and putting them in a list to be folded into a single predicate seems not easy (ie `filter` is easy to apply, but the `&&` and `||` operators are hard to apply (as far as I've tried)). But fortunately it seems we can convert easily a `Boolean` to a `Colunm[Boolean]` to a `Column[Option[Boolean]]` with the `.?` extension method.

So let's define our predicate type:

```
type TablePredicate[Item, T <: Table[Item]] = T => Column[Option[Boolean]]
```

**Folding a list of predicates (ie using conjunctions/disjunctions, ie composing AND and OR clauses)**

Now we only have one type so we can easily fold a list of predicates into a single

```
  // A predicate that never filter the result
  def matchAll[Item, T <: Table[Item]]: TablePredicate[Item,T] = { table: T => LiteralColumn(1) === LiteralColumn(1) }

  // A predicate that always filter the result
  def matchNone[Item, T <: Table[Item]]: TablePredicate[Item,T] = { table: T => LiteralColumn(1) =!= LiteralColumn(1) }

  def conjunction[Item, T <: Table[Item]](predicates: TraversableOnce[TablePredicate[Item, T]]): TablePredicate[Item,T]  = {
    if ( predicates.isEmpty ) matchAll[Item,T]
    else {
      predicates.reduce { (predicate1, predicate2) => table: T =>
        predicate1(table) && predicate2(table)
      }
    }
  }

  def disjunction[Item, T <: Table[Item]](predicates: TraversableOnce[TablePredicate[Item, T]]): TablePredicate[Item,T] = {
    if ( predicates.isEmpty ) matchNone[Item,T]
    else {
      predicates.reduce { (predicate1, predicate2) => table: T =>
        predicate1(table) || predicate2(table)
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**The dynamic filtering case class**

From these predicate primitives we can start creating our dynamic, composable and typesafe query DSL based on a case class.

```
case class UserFilters(
                           companyScopeIds: Option[Set[String]] = None,
                           firstNames: Option[Set[String]] = None,
                           lastNames: Option[Set[String]] = None
                           ) {

  type UserPredicate = TablePredicate[User,UserTable]


  def withFirstNames(firstNames: Set[String]): UserFilters = this.copy(firstNames = Some(firstNames))
  def withFirstNames(firstNames: String*): UserFilters = withFirstNames(firstNames.toSet)

  def withLastNames(lastNames: Set[String]): UserFilters = this.copy(lastNames = Some(lastNames))
  def withLastNames(lastNames: String*): UserFilters = withLastNames(lastNames.toSet)

  def withCompanyScopeIds(companyScopeIds: Set[String]): UserFilters = this.copy(companyScopeIds = Some(companyScopeIds))
  def withCompanyScopeIds(companyScopeIds: String*): UserFilters = withCompanyScopeIds(companyScopeIds.toSet)


  private def filterByFirstNames(firstNames: Set[String]): UserPredicate = { table: UserTable => table.firstName inSet firstNames }
  private def filterByLastNames(lastNames: Set[String]): UserPredicate = { table: UserTable => table.lastName inSet lastNames }
  private def filterByCompanyScopeIds(companyScopeIds: Set[String]): UserPredicate = { table: UserTable => (table.companyScopeId.? inSet companyScopeIds) }


  def predicate: UserPredicate = {
    // Build the list of predicate options (because filters are actually optional)
    val optionalPredicates: List[Option[UserPredicate]] = List(
      firstNames.map(filterByFirstNames(_)),
      lastNames.map(filterByLastNames(_)),
      companyScopeIds.map(filterByCompanyScopeIds(_))
    )
    // Filter the list to remove None's
    val predicates: List[UserPredicate] = optionalPredicates.flatten
    // By default, create a conjunction (AND) of the predicates of the represented by this case class
    conjunction[User,UserTable](predicates)
  }

}
```

Notice the usage of `.?` for the `companyScopeId` field which permits to fit a non-optional column to our definition of a Slick predicate

**Using the DSL**

```
val Users = TableQuery(new UserTable(_))

val filter1 = UserFilters().withLastNames("lorber","silhol").withFirstName("robert")
val filter2 = UserFilters().withFirstName("sebastien")

val filter = disjunction[User,UserTable](Set(filter1.predicate,filter2.predicate))

val users = Users.filter(filter.predicate).list

// results in 
// ( last_name in ("lorber","silhol") AND first_name in ("robert") ) 
// OR 
// ( first_name in ("sebastien") )
```

**Conclusion**

This is far from being perfect but is a first draft and at least can give you some inspiration :) I would like Slick to make it easier to build such things that are very common in other query DSL (like Hibernate/JPA Criteria API)

See also this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/cvogt/9193220) for up-to-date solutions

Comment: I already see you creating a new repository on github named "slick-criteria" ;) good work, Sebastien!

Comment: thanks :) yes that could be a nice idea, even if the project would not contain much things

Comment: Wow this is gold! Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

"fold" is already the keyword here. Or "reduce" since you don't need a seeding value. `buildFilter.reduce(_ && _)`

Comment: I read about "dynamic filtering" a couple of times in the last days on stackoverflow. Maybe it is worth documenting it. What do you think? I could help.

Comment: Yes it is a feature that everybody building an UI with form filters need. I'm kind of surprised this is not a main feature provided by Slick for querying as it's so commun. Hibernate and JPA have the Criteria API for years

Comment: I don't quite understand. .filter in combination with .reduce or .fold is an excellent way to do this. What else do you need? Slick's composability makes it happen, which is a main feature of Slick.

Comment: Documenting it is a good idea. Would be great if someone could submit a PR. http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.1.0/ (See edit this page on github on the top)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like to want a more general version of this: [Dynamic OR filtering - Slick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171245/dynamic-or-filtering-slick). I think my last example on this page is exactly what you want - it is just what cvogt proposes. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Thoefer this is a nice idea that I'll investigate. However in your exemple all the predicates seems to have the same `shape` I mean your list  of predicates are all either `Column[Boolean]`, or all `Colunm[Option[Boolean]]`. Also I'd like the folded filter to actually remain composable, to be able to compose very complex conjunctions and disjunctions. Something like `filter1.build && filter2.build || filter3.build` where each of the 3 parts is already a folded set of predicates.

Comment: Glad it helps! To me this sounds like something that should to be on top of slick, I do not think this is possible out of the box with slick. Hope you share a possible solution, sounds interesting.

Comment: Actually I'm starting to succeed. It seems I can convert a `Colunm[Boolean]` predicate to `Column[Option[Boolean]]` using `.?`, thus being able to make my list homogenous under a common type on which I'm able to call `&&` or `||`. I've written a fold function which combines predicate functions (with table parameter). It's a just a little bit more complicated but not so much. Will try to see where it goes and post an answer here

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the same thing, and came across this question - the accepted answer was a very heavy inspiration to what I eventually landed on. Details are [here](https://gitlab.com/snippets/1672828).

The only comments I'd make about the accepted answer - `TablePredicate[Item, T <: Table[Item]]` can just be simplified to `TablePredicate[T <: Table[_]]` because Item is never used (at least in the sample). `LiteralColumn(1) === LiteralColumn(1)` can also just be `LiteralColumn(Some(true))` (makes the generated queries slightly less awkward) - I'm pretty sure with a little more work, these could be eliminated entirely.