# How to filter composite primary key in Slick 3

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0

I'm new to Slick 3. I want to filter composite primary key as follows that query by using Slick.

```
SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE (pk1, pk2) IN (("a1", "a2"), ("b1", "b2"));
```

I know that Slick can filter multiple conditions like

```
TestTableQuery.filter(t => t.pk1 === "a1" && t.pk2 === "a2")
```

Additionally, I know that Slick can filter multiple values(That means IN caluse.) like

```
val pkSeq = Seq("a1", "b1")
TestTableQuery.filter(t => t.pk1.inSet(pkSeq))
```

So, I want to write as describe below if it's possible.

```
val pk1AndPk2Seq = Seq(("a1", "a2"), ("b1", "b2"))
TestTableQuery.filter(t => (t.pk1, t.pk2).inSet(pk1AndPk2Seq))
```

Is there something way? Thank you.

Comment: I think you need to define primary key in your table definition. For example `def compositePk = primaryKey("pk_a", (pk1, pk2))` and then query it like `TestTableQuery.filter(_.compositePk.inSet(pk1AndPk2Seq))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I challenge your advice, but I didn't find a "inSet" method in PrimaryKey class..

Comment: I am afraid that you need to use plain sql query to archive desired functionality

Comment: I found solution to this issue in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26815913/how-to-do-or-filter-in-slick